# Mongoose doesn't return custom ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which holds an array of questions in mongo.

```
questions:[
{ 
  "_id" : 1,
  "question" : "Some question",
  "type" : "type"
}]
```

I've defined a schema like this:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  question: String
, type: String
})

var Model = mongoose.model('question', schema)
```

and after the query:

```
new Model.find({}, function(err,records) {
  console.log(records[0]._id)
  res.render('question/index', {title: 'question', question: records})
})
```

I get `undefined` on the console or `null` (if the ID is 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your `_id` values are something other than ObjectIDs, you need to define that in your schema.  I'd also suggest defining your `type` field with an object to avoid potential problems because that keyword has special meaning in schema definitions.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  question: String,
  type: {type: String}
});
```